# jquery function not working properly for dynamically created checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Getting table cells values on checkbox selection

```
//function to get table cells values    
function n() {
  $('.m').on('click',function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".t").text();
    var p= $(this).closest("tr").find(".t1").text();
    $('#c').append('<span>', id, '</span>');
  });
} 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  div.innerHTML="<table><tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='m' onclick=n()></td><td class='m'>data</td><td class='t1'>data</td></tr></table>";
}
//appending values on checkbox selection
<div id='c'></div>
```

While checkbox selected getting values of table rows in function n() in above example, but value appends in `div#c`, in such way as on first checkbox click goes 2 times, on second click 3 times prints and so on.

Why this happens?

Comment: Fix your markup please

Comment: not getting?markup means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **event Delegation**

Change

```
$('.m').on('click',function()
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.m', function()
```

And it's a bad practice to use inline events. You always have an option of attaching events in javascript..

Also the way you were binding events binds the events multiple times for each checkbox in the table. That is because , whenever you click on a checkbox, you call the `function n()`. This selects all the elements with `class="m"` and attaches the events on them.

The way you were supposed to handle that was passing the `this` context to the function and completely remove the event handling signature from inside the function.

You code should look like below.

```
$(document).on('click', '.m',function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".t").text();
    var p= $(this).closest("tr").find(".t1").text();
    $('#c').append('<span>', id, '</span>');
  });

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  div.innerHTML="<table><tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='m'></td>"
                + "<td class='m'>data</td><td class='t1'>data</td></tr></table>";
}
//appending values on checkbox selection
<div id='c'></div>
```

**UPDATE**

You have incorrect closing tags and the structure has many syntax errors. Also remove the `function n()` which is called from `onclick=n()` as you are already binding the event in javascript. Your code should look like below

```
<style>
    .c:hover { color:red; };
    .li { };
</style>

<script>
    // document Ready handler
    $(function () {
        // Click event for elements with class m 
        $(document).on('click', '.m', function () {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".t").text();
            var p = $(this).closest("tr").find(".t1").text();
            $('#c').append('<li class="li">id<span class ="c">X</span></li >');
        });
        // Click events for elemenst with class c
        $(document).on('click', '.c ', function () {
            $(this).closest("li").remove() alert("ok");
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

This line

```
$('#c').append('<li class="li">id<span class ="c">X</span></li >');
```

supposed to be

```
$('#c').append('<li class="li">'+ id + '<span class ="c">X</span></li >');
```

And

```
$('#cart1').append('<span id=li1>',id,+p,+q ,"Amount="+p*q,'<span class=close>X</span></span>','</br>');
```

Supposed to be

```
$('#cart1').append('<span id="li1">' + id + p + q + 'Amount=' + (p * q) + '<span class=close>X</span></span></br>');
```

Comment: thnx-@Sushanth..........its working

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: -@Sushanth..function n() {
  $('.m').on('click',function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".t").text();
    var p= $(this).closest("tr").find(".t1").text();
    $('#c').append('<li class='li'>',id,<span class='c'>'"X"'</span>','</li>');
  });
} 
<style>
.c:hover
{
color:red;
}
.li
{
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.c',function()           
{

    $(this).closest("li").remove()
    alert("ok");
});

</script> 
on clicking this 'X' symbol i want to delete that list,'OK' in alert printed but remove function not working why?

Comment: still its not working ,it does not allow to write as you wrote in above code $('#c').append('<li class="li">id<span class ="c">X</span></li >');..it prints id as it is....but if line$(this).closest("li").remove() if use "span" instead of "li" it removes that "X" symbol ,bt if i wrote, $('#cart1').append('<span id=li1>',id,+p,+q ,"Amount="+p*q,'<span class=close>X</span></span>','</br>');  not working

Comment: check edited post.. I missed that id is a variable.. Also use `+` instead of comma to append strings